# rsync general question

Tags: linux, rsync

Hallo!

I'm trying to use rsync.

At first, everything looks very good:
http://paste2.org/p/1180092

After that, i copied some of the files manually and runned rsync again in dry mode:

http://paste2.org/p/1180100

Why hasn't changed something in the --stats, although only the permissions and the timestamp have to be updated and not the full files need to be copied?

greetings

Comment: Why are you making us go to paste2.org to see your output? Put it in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously because nothing in the file contents need to be changed - so no more data is moved between the servers except the metadata that is always exchanged.

BTW - this is more of a ServerFault question then a StackOverflow question..